# How to create a new table with partition key and sort key with AWS-Amplify?

Tags: ionic4, aws-amplify

I need to add a sort key and partition key to an existing dynamo db table... I created a new table with a partition key and sort key manual. But when I try to get one separate from the table it gives an error called "The provided key element does not match the schema". For that reason, I want to create a new table with a partition key and sort key. How can I edit my graphql schema and do a amplify push to create a new table? Please help... following is my graphql schema

```
type Idea @model
 {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  userName: String
  category: String!
  status:String
  OtherCategory: String
  description: String
  subCategory: String   
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "IdeaComments")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the new `@key` directive that was added to Amplify's GraphQL Transformer: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#key

Comment: Hi Richard. I've been using GraphQL with some of the auto generated (get, list etc..). I want to be able to retrieve my hash key. Would you kindly be able to assist here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929031/how-do-i-use-a-global-secondary-index-in-dynamodb-to-get-the-id-of-a-user-in-m